# Photo Gallery / Grid for Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm really liking Twitter Bootstrap so far and am finding it fairly easy to implement. The next step is to implement some-type of photo gallery for some pages and for future blog posts. Ideally I would like rows of photos (perhaps 4/row) with nice small borders and pop-up enlarged images either when (a) clicked on or (b) hovered over. I did some research and was unable to find any tutorials or ways how to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [the](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#media) ? Or at [those](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/) [articles](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/) ?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the documentation. However, it doesn't include information about any pop-up image viewer. If you could make a suggestion as to which script(s) to use that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It includes link to such information. Try [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples), or search the web a bit more, try the scripts you find, and then come back if you encounter a specific problem that you can't resolve by looking at previously asked questions.

Comment: Sherbrow -- could you please show me where on "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails" there is a link to "such information" like Fancybox? Just want to clarify. I will give fancybox a try, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check out https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery
it demonstrates a simple image gallery for bootstrap theres also https://github.com/jbutz/bootstrap-lightbox for a lightbox almost effect.